# If w bosons can create dark matter neutrinos by decay, can they also create dark energy?

Tags: dark-matter, dark-energy, particles

Dark energy is often associated with vacuum energy fluctuations. But the experimentally measured Casimir effect suggests that there is almost no vacuum energy.Because most of the vacuum energy is supposed to be electromagnetic (virtual photons) and the weak force , mediated by w bosons is linked to electromagnetism through electoweak theory, has the energy of electromagnetism in the vacuum been converted into weak force energy - did virtual photons become w bosons at the time of the big bang and are  these a bosons now decaying into various other particles to yield dark energy?

Answer (score 5):

The W boson has a lifetime of $3\times 10^{−25}$ seconds. So any big bang W bosons will have long decayed. So they are not a dark energy source. Also, they produce "hot" relativistic decay products, so they are not the source of the "cold" dark matter we see forming halos.

Comment: The w boson can only decay quickly if its decay products enter an environment in which their energy is low. The fact that dark matter has high energy (5 times mass of bayons) means that the decay products may not be entering a low energy environment. Although why nuclear decay W bosons seem now to be in a low energy environment and the dark energy e bosons are not would need to be explained.